# How to copy all files with a particular prefix to new directories with python?

Tags: python, algorithm

Suppose I have the following directory structure:

```
C:\Test
C:\Test\2009
C:\Test\2009\files\Artists
C:\Test\2009\files\Artists\SnoopDog
C:\Test\2009\files\Artists\SnoopDog\albums.txt
C:\Test\2009\files\Artists\SnoopDog\albums.jpg
C:\Test\2009\files\Artists\SnoopDog\hobbies.doc
C:\Test\2009\files\Artists\SmashMouth\albums.txt
C:\Test\2009\files\Artists\SmashMouth\hobbies.doc
C:\Test\2010\files\Artists\SnoopDog\albums.txt
C:\Test\2010\files\Artists\SnoopDog\albums.jpg
C:\Test\2010\files\Artists\SnoopDog\hobbies.doc
```

The following is the directory structure I want as a goal:

```
C:\ToDirectory\
C:\ToDirectory\2009\albums\SnoopDog_albums.txt
C:\ToDirectory\2009\albums\SnoopDog_albums.jpg
C:\ToDirectory\2009\albums\SmashMouth_albums.txt
C:\ToDirectory\2009\albums\SmashMouth_albums.jpg
C:\ToDirectory\2009\hobbies\SmashMouth_hobbies.doc
C:\ToDirectory\2009\hobbies\SnoopDog_hobbies.doc
C:\ToDirectory\2010\albums\SnoopDog_albums.txt
C:\ToDirectory\2010\albums\SnoopDog_albums.jpg
```

Assuming `C:\Test` contains all the files and `C:\ToDirectory` starts off as being an empty directory.

What is the most efficient way to have a function where I simply give its source directory `C:\Test` and a target directory `ToDirectory` and the script goes to the lowest level of `C:\Test`, goes through each file in the directory and checks whether the filename (ignoring extension) is a durectiry in the `ToDirectory` structure, if not, create it and copy the file into it with the parent directory appended at the beginning of its name with python?

I am using os.listdir and os.isdir in a series of nexted loops, but it appears to be very lengthy and though it does it job, appears inefficient...

Comment: Aside from not showing us you've put any effort into this problem, your problem is highly underspecified.  What happened to the `files` directory?  But wy does the `2009` directory stay the same?  Etc.

Comment: (1) sounds like a homework problem and (2) this is easily solvable using the standard "os" package

Comment: files directory is just a directory that is there, but no one cares about. 2009 directory could be 2010. Edited post to clarify.

Comment: *I am using os.listdir and os.isdir in a series of nexted loops, but it appears to be very lengthy and though it does it job, appears inefficient...* In that case, please post your current code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try pythons high level file operations library ( [import shutil](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html) )

Also consider using pythons excellent directory walking function ( [from os import walk](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk) )

You shouldn't need to copy the files but just rename the directories and filenames.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve shorter code using recursion instead of nesting loops explicitly.

Recursion is not always more efficient but your code will look a lot better!.